# HTML/CSS hide elements that don't fit block, without fixed height

Tags: html, css

Basically, I've split page for two parts (2/3 and 1/3). Left side have dynamic content, and it's main for my grid. Right side have dynamic content too, image + text.

I have following grid:

```css
article {
  width: 66.6%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: red;
}

aside {
  width: 33.4%;
  background: blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  left: 66.6%;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
<article>
   text
   <br>
   text
</article>

  <aside>
    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg">
  </aside>
</div>
```

You see, image is being cut, this is basic overflow logic. But all I want to do, is not to show this picture if it is being overflowed.

Comment: You'd need JavaScript for that

Comment: As I understand there is no other, there is no other way to accomplish this without JS...

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```js
if ($('img').height() > $('article').height()) {
  $('img').css('display', 'none');
}
```

```css
article {
  width: 66.6%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: red;
}

aside {
  width: 33.4%;
  background: blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  left: 66.6%;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <article>
    text
    <br> text
  </article>

  <aside>
    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg">
  </aside>
</div>
```